# how to convert Option<&u8> to u8

Tags: rust

i want to convert Option<&u8> to u8 so i will be able to print it

my code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let v : Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    let out_of_range = &v[100];
    let out_of_range = v.get(100);
    match out_of_range{
        Some(&u8) => println!("data out of range: {}", out_of_range),
        None => println!("bruh"),
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can @NaitikMundra!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your match statement needs the introduction of a *binding*, not a type (the `&u8` you used was not expected here).

Here `Some(val)` matches with something which is an `Option<&u8>`, thus `val` is a binding to the embedded `&u8` (if not `None`, of course).

The example explicitly dereferences `val` as an illustration, and highlights the fact that `val` is not an `u8` but a reference, but it's not required for the following operation (printing).

```rust
fn main() {
    let v: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    for idx in [2, 20, 4] {
        let at_index = v.get(idx);
        match at_index {
            Some(val) => {
                // val has type &u8
                let copy_of_val = *val; // not required, just for the example
                println!("at {} --> {}", idx, copy_of_val);
            }
            None => println!("no value at {}", idx),
        }
    }
}
```